# Issues dealing with fractions using bisection search in python

Tags: python

I need to use bisection search to approximate the square root of a number. I wrote the following code but it only works when my number is greater than 1. If it's a decimal like 0.36 in the following example, my code is just not working. Could you please look at it and give me suggestions on why and how to fix it?

```
x = 0.36
dp = 0.01
numGuesses = 0
low = 0.0
high = x
ans = (high + low)/2.0
while abs(ans**2 - x) >= dp:
    print("low ="+ str(low) + "high = " + str(high) + " ans = "  + str(ans))
    numGuesses += 1
    if ans**2 < x:
        low = ans
    else:
        high = ans
    ans = (high + low)/2.0
print("numGuesses =" + str(numGuesses))
print(str(ans) + "is close to square root of"  + str(x))
```

Comment: Which python version?

Comment: It fails because the solution isn't between initial low and high.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the number is less than 0 then the root of that number will be greater than that. So you should start from 1. Try this

```
x = 0.36
dp = 0.01
numGuesses = 0
low = 0.0
high = x
ans = 0
if x> 1:
    ans = (high + low)/2.0
else:
    ans = 1
while abs(ans**2 - x) >= dp:
    print("low ="+ str(low) + "high = " + str(high) + " ans = "  + str(ans))
    numGuesses += 1
    if ans**2 < x:
        low = ans
    else:
        high = ans
    ans = (high + low)/2.0
print("numGuesses =" + str(numGuesses))
print(str(ans) + "is close to square root of"  + str(x))
```

Comment: this works perfectly, thank you so much for your help!!